# Application Services Composition

Tags: c#, service, repository, domain-driven-design

I've a Customer entity that has an referente to City:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set;}
}
```

Then, the following application service:

```
public class CustomerService
{
    private readonly ICustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public void RegisterCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        //Do another things...

        customerRepository.Save(customer);
    }
}
```

To register a new customer the service consumer would have to have access to a listing of cities to put in CityId, such as get the list of cities to fill a combobox.

Thus it would be necessary provide a list city operation.

Should i add this operation to CustomerService?

Like:

```
public class CustomerService
{
    private readonly ICustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private readonly ICityRepository cityRepository;

    public ServicoCliente(
        ICustomerRepository customerRepository, 
        ICityRepository cityRepository)
    {
        this.customerRepository= customerRepository;
        this.cityRepository= cityRepository;
    }

    public void RegisterCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        customerRepository.Save(customer);
    }

    public List<City> ListCities()
    {
        return cityRepository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Or create a new Service:

```
public class CityService
{
    private readonly ICityRepository cityRepository;

    public CityService(ICityRepository cityRepository)
    {
        this.cityRepository= cityRepository;
    }

    public List<City> ListCities()
    {
        return cityRepository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

In the latter case the consumer should have references two services to be able to complete one operation: RegisterCustomer.

Which approach to follow? What are the advantages and disadvantages of this?

Comment: what is application scope. (users/ client, ) ?

Comment: Is City really an entity or is it a value object? See http://www.jefclaes.be/2013/05/accidental-entities-you-dont-need-that.html Is getting a list of cities really part of your domain, or is this just a query? You probably don't need the service/repository bloat. http://www.jefclaes.be/2014/01/repositories-where-did-we-go-wrong_26.html

Comment: Hi @JefClaes, Is City really an entity or is it a value object? R: Yes, City is an entity and is referenced by another entities besides Customer (Changes in cities will be reflected in all entities that use it).

Is getting a list of cities really part of your domain, or is this just a query? 
R: Is just a query but need be used to provide Customers CityId.

Comment: Inject the repository into the CustomerService, services can use other repositories to lookup things.

Comment: Yes, it looks better to me than the another approach but there are some rule to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a code organization issue and has little to do with DDD.

> public class **Customer**Service {
>
> public List List**Cities**()
>     {
>         return cityRepository.GetAll();
>     }
>
> }

There's an obvious mismatch here -- you don't expect from a Customer service public interface method to return cities. This breaks the principle of least surprise and will cause a lot of searching and head scratching for generations of developers to come.

A dedicated service seems like a better idea to me.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you about it, but let's say that ListCities does an query that return only allowed cities for customers (Domain specific requeriments)". Does this query have to be in ICityService or ICustomerService?

Comment: Same here -- `CityService.ListCustomerCities()` or something along those lines

Comment: List*CUSTOMER*Cities() on the I*CITY*Service 

has the same problem that 

List*CITIES*() on I*CUSTOMER*Service...

Comment: I don't think so. It returns Cities so naturally belongs in a City service. It's still a service about cities, not customers.